# PHP remove special character '%' from string

Tags: php, string, replace, special-characters

I would like to remove '%'

```
echo '<a href="/coupon/'.$post->slug.'/'.$dcount.'/'.strtolower(str_replace(' ','-', $drow['title'])).'" target="_blank">';
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You already know the function to replace stuff: `str_replace()`, so where is the problem?

Comment: for some reason is not working...can you provide example?

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? Do you get any errors? Add [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Where are you trying to replace `%`? What contains `%`? Have your tried `urlencode`; http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php?

Comment: I guess my issue is how to combine more than one...since im replacing an empty space with a ' - ' ,  how can i add the '%' character in the same str_replace.

Comment: @JoseSalazar Read the manual about [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#refsect1-function.str-replace-parameters)

Comment: You want to replace both space and `%` with `-`?

Comment: @TareqMahmood Yes, that will be perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` instead with Regular Expression

```
preg_replace('/[ %]/','-', $drow['title']))
```

Learn about `preg_replace` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Learn about Regular Expression : http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

```
str_replace([' ','%'], ['-','&#37;'], $drow['title']);
```

`str_replace` lets you specify multiple replacements, as above.  Not sure what your wanted to replace `%` with so I put `&#37;` which is the HTML-escaped symbole for `%`.